# How to get associative array from url query string, javascript

Tags: javascript

I have url query string

```
?filter%5B%22customer_rating_heading%22%5D=customer_rating_6_up%2Ccustomer_rating_7_up%2Ccustomer_rating_9_up&map=1
```

which is

```
?filter["customer_rating_heading"]=customer_rating_6_up,customer_rating_7_up,customer_rating_9_up&map=1
```

I want to ask for `filter` like `params.get('filter)` and get

```
[customer_rating_heading => 'customer_rating_6_up,customer_rating_7_up,customer_rating_9_up' //(later I'll make array from this string)
```

But I don't know how to do this, I tried `let query = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(location.search)` but it gives me:

```
{filter["customer_rating_heading"]: "customer_rating_6_up,customer_rating_7_up,customer_rating_9_up"
map: "1"}
```

but I can't get filter like `query.filter` it's always undefined

does anyone know a solution for such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [URLSearchParams.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/entries). Here is an example:

```
let query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

for(var pair of query.entries()) {
  console.log("Filter:",pair[0]); // "filter['customer_rating_heading']"
  console.log("Result:",pair[1]) // "customer_rating_6_up,customer_rating_7_up,customer_rating_9_up"
}
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/BajBgza) for you to try.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to access your filter you can use that snippet:

```
let [filter] = Object.keys(query).map( key => query[key] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with "match"

```js
let query = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(location.search))

let firstKey = Object.keys(query)[0];
let found = firstKey.match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1]

let key = found.replace(/\"/g, '');
let value = query[firstKey];



console.log(`${key} => ${value}`)
```